# Gradient of the image

Tags: image-processing, gradient-flows

I'm trying to make a gradient flow for an image. For a test I made a small image 3x3 pixels with a black pixel in the middle.

I found how to compute the direction of the gradient for one point given by coordinates (x,y)

$$\varphi (x,y)=arctan\frac{G_{y}}{G_{x}}$$

Using Sobel operator I got these gradients:
$$G_x = \begin{bmatrix}
255 & 0 & -255 \\ 
510 &  0& -510\\ 
255 & 0 & -255 
\end{bmatrix}, G_y = \begin{bmatrix}
255 & 510 & 255 \\ 
0 &  0& 0\\ 
-255 & -510 & -255 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I also computed the gradient magnitude:

$$\left \| G\right \|^{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
 130050.00 & 260100.00 & 130050.00\\ 
 260100.00& 0 & 260100.00\\ 
 130050.00& 260100.00 &130050.00 
\end{bmatrix}$$

but I have no idea how to make an image with the arrows representing the direction of the gradient. Could anyone please explain me how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the $\arctan$ or $|| \cdot ||^2$.  The coordinates of your arrow are directly given by $G_x$ and $G_y$.  Also the expression for the square nom is a bit suspicious since it is not simply a convolution.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of the arrow's coordinates (or angle) for the first pixel? I'm sorry, but I still don't understand, because I have the picture 3x3, but values are much greater (255 and 510).